# Trying to inject an object into JUnit test

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have had to adapt a project I've been working on to work differently, using an injected object (documentDao) to access the methods for adding/updating/etc. records in a database.  Where necessary I simply injected this object into the constructor, but of course this won't work with JUnit tests (which can only have no-argument constructors), so I'm stuck on how to get the object into the test class.

The first code snippet shows a dumbed-down version of one of the test classes.  The problem is that I need to create the documentDao object so I can pass it as an argument into the BackendApiController instantiation statement.

The second snippet is the first part of the DocumentDaoImpl class, which needs to be injected.

Any suggestions would be welcomed.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class ApiBackendTests {

    @Configuration
    @PropertySource(value = "classpath:system.properties")
    static class ContextConfiguration {
    }

    private static BackendApiController backendApiController = new BackendApiController(documentDao);

@Test
    public void retrieveSampleStatementList() {

        String response = backendApiController.genericStatementList(x,y,z);

        String eStatementId = "";

        if (response.indexOf("_id") > 0) {

            eStatementId = response.substring(response.indexOf("<_id>") + 5, response.indexOf("</_id>"));
        }

        // if this test is true, then at least one statement document was found in the above search.
        assertTrue(response.indexOf("_id") > 0);
    }
}




@Repository
public class DocumentDaoImpl<T> implements DocumentDao<T> {

    public DocumentDaoImpl() {
    }

    @Inject
    DBCollection dbCollection;

    @Inject
    GridFS gridFS;

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    public String insert(CommonDocument document) {
```

Comment: if you are using @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) you can inject anything in your junit test class.

Comment: For populating objects or mocking purpose use Mockito.

Comment: JEY:  This is the thing I'm not clear about -- how to do the injecting.

Comment: prashant:  I  need an actual object here, not a mocked one.  This object is being used to access the database, so it can't just be a placeholder.

Comment: @SCRawl  I don't think you understand the purpose of unit testing.  We're all assuming you're trying to test backendApiController.genericStatementList) in which case you'd mock the DocumentDao interface.

Comment: are you sure that the context loaded properly? If everything is ok, I think @Autowired DocumentDao documentDao should do it

Comment: @Steve Hall I've tried mocking the documentDao object, and a mocked object won't allow me access to the database, at least if it's mocked the way I've done it, which I'm willing to accept could have been wrong.  But the mocked object I've passed into the BackendApiController object would not return any documents from the genericStatementList method.  When debugging I tested the query used against the database itself, and it should return results.

Comment: @HoàngLong Tried that, and I get this:

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.roler.res.test.ApiBackendTests': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.roler.res.mongodb.dao.DocumentDao

Comment: A five second Google search returned these:http://rdafbn.blogspot.com/2014/01/testing-spring-components-with-mockito.html  http://www.luckyryan.com/2013/06/28/unit-testing-with-mockito/

Comment: I've tried the second of these, which seemed closest to my use case.  And the result is the same:  when I debug the code I can see that the documentDao object has been mocked, but it will not actually access the database.

Answer (score 0):

There's still not enough information to say anything for sure, but I believe you can try using @Autowired to wire up your needed component:

```
@Autowired
private DocumentDao documentDao;
```

You got the error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.roler.res.test.ApiBackendTests': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.roler.res.mongodb.dao.DocumentDao
```

That means Spring isn't aware of the DocumentDao bean yet. There are several ways to do that, but I think the easiest way is putting this in your configuration context:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="package.contain.your.dao"/>
```

It will tell Spring to scan the package in search for components with annotation.

**UPDATE**: since you don't use XML configuration, [@ComponentScan](http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch06s02.html) is the way to go

Comment: I'm using annotations for this project, and I'm new enough to Spring that I've never had to use XML configuration files.  What would be the annotations equivalent?

Comment: @SCRawl: I have updated my answer. Please take a look

Comment: `code`@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.roler.res.mongodb.dao" })
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class ApiBackendTests {

    @Configuration
    @PropertySource(value = "classpath:system.properties")
    static class ContextConfiguration {
    }
    @Autowired
    private DocumentDao documentDao;

    private BackendApiController backendApiController = new BackendApiController(documentDao);`\code`

Comment: I've tried to post the code I'm using, but the syntax eludes me for the moment.  Anyway, I've tried adding the ComponentScan as suggested, and I get the same exception.

Comment: @SCRawl: do you use log4j? The class that handles registering the repositories is org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate. I believe now the best way to locate the problem is to turn on log4j for that class, with level debug. Then you will see what actually happpens.

Comment: I did this, and there are over 6k lines of logs to go through for a single execution of this test class, most of which are no use whatever.  Posting such a log file would, I think, be a gross misuse of your good nature, so I'll just keep it to myself.  On the other hand, I believe that I've gotten this to work by creating a Dao object locally (which, in turn, was done by creating the database connection and other objects from scratch) in the test class, and then passing that instead of relying on the Service class whose job it usually is to do that.

Comment: @SCRawl: wow, 6k lines of log, it's a lot. It's hard to see what went on in that case. You can try to set the log level to warning then, maybe it will tell you something isn't so right when the service gets loading. The local Dao object of course will work, however, I'm not sure if that Dao gets seen in the application context